# Representation Theory - Example of a not-G-stable V

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I'm studying linear representations for algebraic groups for the moment. And I kind of got stuck on some theorem. The existence of a finite linear representation makes use of the fact that $V$ is $G$-stable. I got an idea why this should be but I can't find any examples of the opposite.

I messed up with editing, is it possible to remove this question?

Comment: It appears to me that you are considering a space $V$ of functions on your group itself, maybe polynomial functions on a linear group (meaning inside a group of matrices under multiplication)? If so, then as you observe, the finite-dimensional space of polynomials of a given bounded degree tends to be stabilized by such an action, and this is not surprising. But, as in @Thomas' answer, it is easy to arrange situations where a group action moves a vector outside a specified space. Yes, there is the larger space which _is_ stable, for general reasons... Can you clarify what you really want?

Comment: I'd like an example of an algebraic group (for example given by $(G,\mu,e,\iota)$) where the linear representation with basis $V = \langle x_1,...,x_n \rangle$ isn't stable.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Jban, I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what your $x_i$'s refer to. They appear to be coefficient functions on an ambient affine space in which the group lies...? If so, then when the group acts on that affine space linearly, it will invariably preserve the finite-dimensional space of linear combinations of the coordinate functions.

Comment: I don't know how to make my question more clear but maby an alternative question might also help me. 

I cite (Linear Algebraic Groups, Borel, 1991):
Let F be any finite dimensional vector subspaceof K[V]. Then there is a finite dimensional subspace E which (i) contains F (ii) is definied over k, and (iii) is stable under left translation by G.

What happens if E is unstable? Proof with example

Comment: Ok, this is essentially as I thought. Then @Thomas' answer gives probably the simplest example, with $E=F$ a line in $\mathbb R^2$. It is not stable under $GL_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: What does the $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ stand for? I got the idea as i refer to it as a set, but I miss the connection to an algebraic group.

Comment: Thanx all for commenting and helping me out, i got it (I think)

Comment: As algebraic group, $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ takes a commutative $\mathbb R$-algebra $A$ to $GL_2(A)$. This is a hypersurface in five space by mapping $g\to (g,\det g)$.

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure that I understand your question, but maybe this might help:

Consider $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ with $G= GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ acting the obvious way. In this example the subspace $U = \mathbb{R} = \{(x,0)\mid x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is *not* $G$-stable. You have, for example, that
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}\pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1}.
$$
Here you have a vector in $U$ that is "sent" outside of $U$.

Comment: @Jban: I am still not sure that I understand. Could you edit your question with some more clarification?

Comment: I'll try but what language should i use to just have some normal math symbols, does it support latex?

Comment: @Jban: See for example here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Jban: Ok, so you actually can't just copy LaTeX code directly.

Comment: @Jban: Do this: Use one of the answer here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox to practice the formatting. When you have the question rightly formatted, then edit your question above.

Comment: @Jban: I am still not sure that I understand how your groups is defined and what you want. Sorry.

Comment: @Thomas: It seems to me that you could use the same argument more generally to prove that there are no non-trivial $G$-stable subspaces of $V$?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer: Yes, the representation in the example is irreducible.